# MariaDB error log

Tags: mariadb, error-log, my.cnf

I have `mariadb 10.0.23` on `debian jessie`. I want to check mysql's error log and so I added this line to `my.cnf`:

> log-error = /var/log/mysql/error.log

and then I restarted the service mysql:

> service mysql restart

After that, I checked the path `/var/log/mysql/` but there wasn't any error.log over there.

In addition I checked the system variable `log_error`:

> mysql> show variables like '%error%';

and I saw that the value of the variable `log_error` is **blank** :(

Can anybody help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your variable is `log_error`, but you define `log-error`; all variables are with "_", not with "-". It had hit my head some time ago too.
2. After you do correct it, you must enter `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-mysqld_safe.cnf` and comment the 2 lines: `skip_log_error` and `syslog -> #skip_log_error` and `#syslog`. Otherwise errors will go to the `syslog` and you will wonder where are they. This file should been used only when there is `mysqld_safe` option used when starting `mysqld`, but in fact they are also used when you start normally.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to put that in the `[mysqld]` section of `my.cnf`.

Comment: What does the `SHOW ...` say now?